# Better way to obtain line iterator to the cursor position in a GtkTextBuffer

Tags: c, iterator, cygwin, gtk

I want to obtain an iter at line of the cursor position of a GtkTextBuffer instead of having to specify line index explicitly. What I have came up with is this:

```
gint pos;

g_object_get(buffer, "cursor-position", &pos, NULL);

GtkTextIter temp;
gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_offset(buffer, &temp, pos);
gint line = gtk_text_iter_get_line(&temp);

gtk_text_buffer_get_iter_at_line(buffer, iter, line);
```

Needles to say, it doesn't look very convenient.
I am looking for the **correct** straightforward way to achieve this or something more optimized. Any ideas?